# Why does Microsoft use types like __int32 etc instead of int32_t?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, integer, built-in-types

While browsing the implementation of standard library headers in Visual Studio with C++ 20, I came across the type `__int64`, it looked like a built-in type and I couldn't go to its definition. I googled it and found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/int8-int16-int32-int64?view=msvc-170) by Microsoft. Apparently the types `__int32`, `__int64` etc are Microsoft-specific built-in types.

I wondered why Microsoft uses these types instead of the non-Microsoft-specific `int32_t`, `int64_t` types, shouldn't they achieve the same thing? When I went to the definitions of those, they were just typedefs for types like `int` and `long long`, but I assume the implementation still guarantees that types like `int32_t` have the amount of bits you'd expect. If these types/typedefs are good enough and reliable for the normal user, why does Microsoft use their own ones? If there's an advantage to using these types, why didn't they typedef `int32_t` etc as `__int32` etc? Is there a situation where I might want to use types like `__int32` over `int32_t`?

Comment: Historic reasons, I’m sure. These standardization of int64_t and int33_t are relatively recent. ( C++11) though I do look forward to seeing if someone has an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do so many libraries define their own fixed width integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70082906/why-do-so-many-libraries-define-their-own-fixed-width-integers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because MSVC existed long before C++11 was introduced**. For things that need a fixed size obviously they have to user their own internal type. That's why those have the [`__` prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/995714) because the standard says that names beginning with double underscores are reserved in the global namespace

That's also the reason why lots of libraries define their own fixed-width types or even C and C++ keywords, for exampe gstreamer's `guint32`, `gint`..., OpenCL's `cl_int` and `cl_uint`..., Qt's `quint32`, `quint64`..., boost's `boost::uint32_t`, zlib's `z_off64_t`... because only decades after their advent the standard stdint.h would come into existence

- [Why do so many libraries define their own fixed width integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70082906/995714)
- [Why do c++ libraries often define their own primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30802502/995714)

Comment: Minor point: names that **contain** (not just begin with) two consecutive underscores are reserved. That's a remnant of cfront, which encoded member function names with two underscores between the name of the class and the name of the function.